# Matlab surface plot save as true vector grafic

Tags: matlab, plot, vector-graphics, surface

**Goal:**

I am trying to export a Matlab surface plot as a `.eps` vector-graphics file and include it in a LaTex document. Exporting normal plots as `.eps` using them in the same LaTex document works perfectly fine and they are clearly still vector-graphics after compiling viewing the document using Adobe Reader.

**Example:**

The command `peaks` can be used to create the surface plot shown below (exported as `.png`. And yes, this seriously results in significantly fewer compression artefacts than exporting as an `.eps` file ).

[image: Peaks surface plot]

**Problem:**

If I export the sample plot from above as an `.eps` file, compile my LaTex document and then look at it using Adobe Reader, the plot shows ugly pixel-graphics like compression artefacts, see screenshot below (zoomed-in in Adobe Reader).
The problem is actually so bad that the compression artefacts are even noticeable without zooming in on my 4K screen.

[image: Compression artefacts]

I suspect that Matlab embeds an image into the `.eps` file (if that is possible).
Exporting the figure as an `.svg` results in a pixel-graphic with fewer compression artefacts (it is definitely not a vector-graphic either).

**Question:**

How can I force Matlab to export a surface plot as a true vector-graphic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set the `'Renderer'` property of the figure to `'painters'`:

```
peaks
set(gcf, 'Renderer', 'painters')
print(gcf, '-depsc', 'test.eps')
```

or directly supply this as input argument to print:

```
print(gcf, '-depsc', 'test.eps', '-painters')
```

This will result in true vector graphics. However, I would recommend to export you figures as pdf, since I believe that latex will convert eps to pdf anyway.

If you call `print` with the `-dpdf` driver, Matlab will print the figure on a large paper. To crop the paper to the size of your figure, you can use the following function:

```
function saveFigPdf(fig, filename, figsize, resolution)
% saveFigPdf(fig, filename, figsize, resolution)
% figsize = [width height]

    if ~exist('figsize', 'var') || isempty(figsize)
        figsize = [8, 5];
    end

    if ~exist('resolution', 'var') || isempty(resolution)
        resolution = '-r300';
    end

    % set paper settings
    fig.PaperUnits = 'centimeters';
    fig.PaperPositionMode = 'manual';
    fig.PaperSize = figsize;
    fig.PaperPosition = [0, 0, figsize(1), figsize(2)];
    fig.Renderer = 'painters';

    % print to pdf
    print(fig, '-dpdf', filename, resolution);
end
```